# WPF Office 2007 Theme

Tags: wpf, ms-office, themes

are there any additional WPF themes from microsoft except that default ones provided in
PersentationFrameWork.Aero,
PersentationFrameWork.Luna,
PersentationFrameWork.Royale &
PersentationFrameWork.Classic

i am specially interested in a Office 2007 Blue theme

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you happen to have [Infragistics NetAdvantage](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/wpf.aspx#Overview): it has some Office 2007 themes.

Answer (score 1):

There are some themes at this [link](http://dotnet.org.za/rudi/archive/2008/11/06/wpf-themes-released.aspx) which were converted from Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try www.reuxables.com - we have both commercial and free themes, and it is the largest and most diverse theme library for WPF.